# Generating a Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question that asks me to give a formula that generates a sequence whose first five terms are 2, 4, 6, 8, and pi.

Can anyone give me a good place to start? I thought maybe generating a formula that will give me 22/7 as the fifth term, but I don't think that is equivalent to pi.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Polynomial-interpolation ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: There is a unique polynomial $f(x)$ with degree at most $4$ satisfying $f(1)=2$ , $f(2)=4$ , $f(3)=6$ , $f(4)=8$ , $f(5)=\pi$. Then, the sequence $f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots $ starts with the desired values. (See also the answer below, where we apparently start with $0$)

Comment: "... *that will give me 22/7 as the fifth term, but I don't think that is equivalent to* $\pi$"  $\frac{22}{7}$ is absolutely not equal to $\pi$.  It is well known that $\pi$ is an irrational number and as such cannot be expressed as a ratio of two integers.

Comment: @mbb254 And $\frac{22}{7}$, although often used in practice, is not even a very good approximation. $\frac{355}{113}$ is much better, but still not $\pi$. As pointed out, $\pi$ is irrational, so we cannot write it out anyway, so either your formula will somehow contain $\pi$, or you truncate $\pi$ to get a polynomial giving entries very close to the desired entries.

Comment: $$p(x)=\frac{1}{24} \left((\pi -10) x^4+(100-10 \pi ) x^3+(35 \pi -350) x^2+(548-50 \pi ) x+24 \pi -240\right)$$
$$\begin{array}{l}
 p(1) = 2 \\
 p(2) = 4 \\
 p(3) = 6 \\
 p(4) = 8 \\
 p(5) = \pi  \\
 p(6) = -38+5 \pi  \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Raffaele Formulate this as an answer. I will upvote it!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function $f$ defined over all real numbers such that
the graph of $y=f(x)$ for $x \leq 4$ goes in a straight line through the points
$(x,y)=(1,2),$ $(2,4),$ $(3,6),$ and $(4,8),$
while the graph for $x \geq 4$ goes in a straight line through the points
$(4,8)$ and $(5,\pi)$:
$$
f(x) = \left(\frac\pi2 - 5\right) \lvert x - 4\rvert + \left(\frac\pi2 - 3\right) x - 2 \pi + 20.
$$

I have checked this [using Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)+%3D+(pi%2F2+-+5)+abs(x+-+4)+%2B+(pi%2F2+-+3)+x+-+2+%5Cpi+%2B+20+at+x+%3D+1,2,3,4,5).

And here's another:
$$
f(x) = 2x - (10-\pi) \left\lfloor\frac x5\right\rfloor,
$$
also checked [using WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)+%3D+2x+-+(10-pi)+floor(x%2F5)+at+x+%3D+1,2,3,4,5).

And we haven't even tried a Fourier decomposition yet!

Comment: +1 $2 x-(10-\pi ) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{5}\right\rfloor$ is amazingly simple!

Answer (score 1):

$$p(x)=\frac{1}{24} \left[(\pi -10) x^4+(100-10 \pi ) x^3+(35 \pi -350) x^2+(548-50 \pi ) x+24 \pi -240\right]$$

$\begin{array}{l}
 p(1) = 2 \\
 p(2) = 4 \\
 p(3) = 6 \\
 p(4) = 8 \\
 p(5) = \pi  \\
 p(6) = 5 \pi-38  \\
\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

$$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$
We know, that $f(-2)=2, f(-1)=4, f(0)=6, f(1)=8, f(2)=\pi$

Thus we obtain:
$$\begin{cases}
16a-8b+4c-2d+e&=2\\ 
a-b+c-d+e & =4 \\
e&=6\\ 
a+b+c+d+e & =8 \\
16a+8b+4c+2d+e&=\pi\end{cases}$$
Now solve this system of equations for $a,b,c,d,e$ (for example using Gaussian elimination) and You will obtain:
$$\begin{cases}a=\frac{3}{116}(\pi-6)\\
b=\frac{2}{29}(\pi-6)\\
c=-\frac{3}{116}(\pi-6)\\
d=2-\frac{2}{29}(\pi-6)\\
e=6\end{cases}$$
You can now use the following generating function:
$$u:\mathbb{N}_+\to \mathbb{R}\\
u(n)=f(n-3)$$